# MongoDB: Problem in fetching value based on sub documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPEDw.png)

As You can see in the image, I have a collection name favorite having sub documents as follows:-

```
db.favorites.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b0e6748186c3bbc85911e"),
        "dishes" : [
                ObjectId("5f0acc6927f8233200bebd21")
        ],
        "user" : ObjectId("5f01e46a624b4b10b037cfe7"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-12T13:21:43.783Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-12T13:21:43.783Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Now i have to fetch it using **user** sub document.
I'm querying : -

```
db.favorites.find({user: "5f01e46a624b4b10b037cfe7"}).pretty()
```

But i'm not getting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to find by the object id:

```
db.favorites.find({user: ObjectId("5f01e46a624b4b10b037cfe7")}).pretty()
```

Comment: Yeah Thanx a lot!

Comment: No worries! Can you mark my answer as solved the issue?